# AngularJS: about instantiating the service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a controller:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function (myService) {
    var that = this;

    that.myService = myService;
});
```

a service:

```
.service('myService', function (DataFactory) {

    var listData = [];

    var mockList = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']; 

    var handleData = function (data) {
        listData = data;
    };
```

and html:

```
<button ng-click="myCtrl.myService.handleData()">Go</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in myCtrl.myService.listData>
    {{ item }}
</div>
```

The thing is: I've got a list which contains data from myService.listData, and (with all code above) it works as expected - by updating list on button click.

I've add:

```
that.list = myService.listData
```

and changed

```
item in myCtrl.myService.listData to item in myCtrl.list
```

and the whole thing stopped working.

Could you explain that to me? I feel like I'm missing some really basic stuff and I need the direction to start searching more info.

plunks: 
[working one](http://plnkr.co/edit/uTVahOiNBZ7jgzsMzog7?p=preview)
[broken](http://plnkr.co/edit/ytxvOJQeWm25n8V1S3UJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b9NAwNFVwvdgs7GrMBes?p=preview).

Your misconception was that you expect `that.myService` to be updated when underlying list is populated on click by `handleData()`.

However, look at your `handleData()` implementation:

```
listData = data;
```

You don't mutate the initial list, **you're pointing to another one** (therefore referencing a distinct list) since it acts as a complete re-assignement!

So one way to solve the problem would be to mutate the initial list:

```
var handleData = function (data) {
    // populating elements into the initial list
    Array.prototype.push.apply(listData, mockedList); 
};
```